# AngularJS: How to access variable created inside unless statement

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am calling API call inside angularJS controller. API code below,

```
unless $scope.apiCall?.data?
  Temp.data.query {id: $scope.id}, (response,err) ->
    $scope.apiCall.data = response
else
  $scope.data = $scope.apiCall.data.unit
```

But I would like to access data from '$scope.apiCall.data' after 'unless else' code is executed and use Lodash library. Is there any way to access the data?

My code is AngularJS and written in CoffeeScript file. Above code is tested and working.

I would appreciate the help. :)

Comment: is `Temp.data.query` an asynchronous callback? You might need to treat it like [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which needs to be resolved every time you need to access `$scope.apiCall.data`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying @AlekseySolovey ... The API call is an asynchronous callback. If I decide to keep API call asynchronous then Is it a good way to use Lodash library inside Unless statement? Or should I use Lodash Library after calling API?  Sorry for asking a new question. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with coffeescript, but you might need something like: `promise = Temp.data.query ...` and then your *else* becomes: `promise.then(res -> $scope.data = res)` (once again, **resolve** it every time you need the data)